# how to good organize folder structure in flutter clean architecture

Tags: flutter, mvvm, clean-architecture

I use Flutter clean architecture MVVM and I have couple of questions:

We can split sending request to API in 2 stages:
- first - call is going throught whole app (View -> View Model -> Model) to API as a **request**
- second - result of our call came from API and go throught all app (Model -> View Model -> View)                                                       as a **response**

I have 2 folders with models:

- in View Model I have folder called as **entities**
- in Model I have folder called as **models**

In first stage I have payload model which is placed entities folder. In this payload I have extension with method toModel which basically converting payload to final model (which structure is placed in models folder). Final object is being sent as a body (or params in header whatever) in API call.

In second stage I get response from API which is mapped to model placed in models folder. In this model I have extension toEntity which converting model to final entity (placed in entites folder).

So in result in entites folder I have 2 types of classes in entities - Entity and Payload and 2 type of classes in models - converted payload and response from API. Does it make sens to keep them separated in folder structure like:

```
   -entities
     -entity
     -payload

   -models
     -model
     -dto
```

where payload -> dto (in first stage) and model -> entity (in second stage).

1. Does it make sens to separate these 2 types of classes in these folders?
2. Is it appropriate to call it as "dto" in Model layer?
3. Sometimes payload is the same or almost the same as dto, also the same situation is in case of model and entity. Should I use in this case inheritance mechanism? e.g.

My payload:

```
@unfreezed
class AddTaskPayload with _$AddTaskPayload {
  factory AddTaskPayload({
    String? title,
    String? description,
    DateTime? date,
    TimeOfDay? startingTime,
    TimeOfDay? endingTime,
    TaskPriority? priority,
  }) = _AddTaskPayload;
}

extension AddTaskPayloadExtension on AddTaskPayload {
  AddTaskModel get toModel {
    final String startingDate = DateTime(date!.year, date!.month, date!.day,
            startingTime!.hour, startingTime!.minute)
        .toIso8601String();

    final String endingDate = DateTime(date!.year, date!.month, date!.day,
            endingTime!.hour, endingTime!.minute)
        .toIso8601String();

    return AddTaskModel(
      title: title,
      description: description,
      startingDate: startingDate,
      endingDate: endingDate,
      priority: priority?.getIntFromPriority(),
    );
  }
}
```

my DTO:

```
@unfreezed
class AddTaskModel with _$AddTaskModel {
  factory AddTaskModel({
    String? title,
    String? description,
    String? startingDate,
    String? endingDate,
    int? priority,
  }) = _AddTaskModel;

  factory AddTaskModel.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      _$AddTaskModelFromJson(json);
}
```

Does it make sens to use in this case inheritance in DTO? 2 fields have the same type (title and description) and rest is different. If not when it make sens to use inheritance?